# K-Algebras in which every subalgebra generated by single element is one-dimensional

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am looking for informations (structural theorems, classifications, examples) about K-algebras (K is a field of arbitrary characteristic) in which the following condition holds:
$$\forall_{x\in A}\exists_{k\in K} x^2=kx.$$
I do not know if such algebras have a common name in literature.
An obvious example here is $K=\mathbb{Q}$ and $A=\mathbb{Q}$ and all subalgebras of $A$ (for instance $\mathbb{Z}$). Does there exists a noncommutative algebra of this kind? What if we assume that $A$ is a domain? (integral domain? reduced?). I will be grateful for information on this topic (links to articles, lecture notes). Unfortunately, I could not find anything valuable. 
Thank you in advance

Comment: Suppose that $x \in A$ is not in the embedded field $K$, and that $x^2 = kx$ for some $k \in K$. Then $(1 + x)^2 = 1 + (2 + k)x$, so unless $k$ happened to be $-2$, the element $1 + x$ cannot satisfy the property you've given. So I think finding examples of algebras of dimension $\geq 2$ where this holds will be very hard...

Comment: Hi. I do not assume that algebra A is unitary, so subalgebra of A may be without an identity element.